# Is the restriction of a smooth vector bundle to an embedded submanifold also embedded

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

This is the definition of a restriction of a vector bundle given in John Lee's Introduction to Smooth Manifolds.

Let $E,M$ be smooth manifolds with or without boundary and $\pi:E \to M$ a rank-$k$ smooth vector bundle and $S$ be an embedded submanifold with or without boundary of $M$. Then we have the restriction of $E$ to $S$ given by the set $E|_S = \bigcup_{p \in S} E_p$ with the projection $E|_S \to S$ obtained by restricting $\pi$.

If $\Phi: \pi^{-1}(U) \to U \times R^k$ is a local trivialization of $E$ over $U \subset M$ it restricts to a bijective map $\Phi|_U : (\pi|_S)^{-1}(U \cap S) \to (U \cap S) \times R^k$ and these form local trivializations for a smooth vector bundle structure on $E|_S$ by the chart lemma.

My question is if $S$ is embedded, is $E|_S$ also embedded in $E$?

I think this is true, because from the chart lemma, first for $E$, we have for each $p \in M$, choose some $U_\alpha$ containing $p$ and choose a smooth chart $(V_p,\phi_p)$ for $M$ such that $p \in V_p \subset U_\alpha$ and let $\hat{V_p} = \phi_p(V_p) \subset R^n$ or $H^n$ (where $n$ is the dimension of $M$). Define a map $\tilde{\phi_p}:\pi^{-1}(V_p)\to \hat{V_p}\times R^k$ by $\tilde{\phi_p}=(\phi_p \times Id_{R^k} )\circ \Phi_\alpha :$
$$ \pi^{-1}(V_p)\to V_p\times R^k \to \hat{V_p}\times R^k.$$ Then $\{(\pi^{-1}(V_p),\tilde{\phi_p}):p\in M\}$become the charts for $E$ and the topology for $E$ is given by taking all sets of the form $\tilde{\phi_p}^{-1}(\hat{V_p}\times W)$ where $W$ is open in $R^k$ as a basis.

Now we can do the same for $E|_S$. Since $S$ has a subspace topology of $M$, for each for each smooth chart $(W_p,\psi_p)$ for $S$ that we choose, and the maps $\tilde{\psi_p}=\Phi|_{U_\alpha}\circ (\psi_p \times Id_{R^k})$, $W_p$ is of the form $V_p \cap S$ where $V_p$ is open in $M$. Hence the basis elements of $E|_S$ is given by $\tilde{\psi_p}^{-1}(\hat{W_p}\times U)$ where $U$ is an open set in $R^k$ and will be given by $\Phi_\alpha^{-1}((V_p\cap S)\times U) = \Phi_\alpha^{-1}((V_p \times U) \cap (S \times R^k)) = \Phi_\alpha^{-1}(V_p \times U) \cap \Phi_\alpha^{-1}(S \times R^k)$. Now $\Phi_\alpha^{-1}(V_p \times U)$ will be an open set in $E$ as $V_p \times U$ is open in $M \times R^K$, and $\Phi_\alpha^{-1}(S \times R^k)$ is just $\pi^{-1}(S)= E|_S$. So this is exactly a basis element of the subspace topology of $E|_S$ with respect to $E$.

Is this argument correct?

Comment: The restriction $E|_S$ is just the pull back bundle by the embedding $i:S\rightarrow M$, so there might be a simpler way to argue this.

Comment: Also the topology on $E$ is not given by taking $\phi^{-1}(U\times R^k)$ as a basis, as this doesn’t locally give you the product topology

Comment: @Chris So is it true that $E|_S$ is embedded in $E$ if $S$ is embedded in $M$? I don't know what the pull back bundle is it's not described in the book so I can't come up with an argument using it. Yes I made a mistake basis should be of the form $\phi^{-1}(U \times W)$ where $W$ is open in $R^k$. I fixed my argument could you check it?